# UI-router overriding parent view from child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is a snippet of my $stateProvider in a demo ionic app.

```
.state('test', {
  template: "test <div ui-view='content'></div>"
})
.state('test.main', {
  url: '/test',
  views: {
    'content': {
      template: "test content2 <div ui-view='content'></div>",
      controller: function() {
        console.log('test content');
      }
    }
  }
})
.state('test.main.now', {
  url: '/now',
  views: {
    'content': {
      template: 'test content now',
      controller: function() {
        console.log('test content now');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

when i request /test/now i see

test
test content2
test content now

which is what i expect to see. When i change the test.main.now's content name to content@ (which should mean override view in parent state) i now get

test
test content2

which is not what i expected. What is the proper way to override the same named view in a parent state? I updated the question with more details and a better example.

Comment: it's hard to check your code, can you provide some demo?

Comment: what **do** you see when you go to `/test/now`? because from what I see, you have a url for `/test` and one for `/now`, but not one for `/test/now`

Comment: Doh, i kept reading this as since i am on the test.main.now state it would assume my route would be /test/now. I was seeing test content and that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In this case i needed to target the route test and not test.main even though I assumed I would only need to target one state chain up.

```
.state('test.main.now', {
  url: '/now',
  views: {
    'content@test': {
```